# golang: how to bind code with thread?

Tags: multithreading, go

I have nearly implemented a face recognition Go server. My face recognition algorithm uses `caffe`, `caffe` is a thread-binding graphical library, that means I have to init and call algorithm in same thread, so I checked [LockOSThread()](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/LockOSThread).

`LockOSThread` uses 1 thread, but my server owns 4 GPU.

In `C/C++`, I could create 4 threads, initialize algorithm in each thread, use `sem_wait` and `sem_post` to assign task, 1 thread use 1 GPU.

How to do the same thing in `Go`, how to bind code with thread?

Comment: There are no "threads" in Go, so you simply cannot do this. But you can take e.g. 4 goroutines and lock each of them to a thread (hopefully 4 different) wit LockOSThread.

Comment: @Volker LockOSThread prevents any other goroutine from using that same thread, so you're guaranteed they'll be on four different threads. https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#LockOSThread

Answer (score 4):

You spawn *some number* of goroutines, run `runtime.LockOSThread()` in each
and then initialize your graphical library in each.

You then use regular Go communication primitives to send tasks to those
goroutines.  Usually, the most simple way is to have each goroutine read "tasks" from a channel and send the results back, like in

```
type Task struct {
  Data DataTypeToContainRecognitionTask
  Result chan<- DataTypeToContainRecognitionResult
}

func GoroutineLoop(tasks <-chan Task) {
  for task := range tasks {
    task.Result <- recognize(Data)
  }
}

tasks := make(chan Task)
for n := 4; n > 0; n-- {
  go GoroutineLoop(tasks)
}

for {
  res := make(chan DataTypeToContainRecognitionResult)
  tasks <- Task{
    Data: makeRecognitionData(),
    Result: res,
  }

  result <- res
  // Do something with the result
}
```

As to figuring out how much goroutines to start, there exist different
strategies.
The simplest approach is probably to query `runtime.NumCPU()`
and using this number.